# MVC 6 .NET Core vs. .NET Framework 4.6 performance comparison

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I searched on the Internet, but I could not find the performance comparison of these technologies

- **ASP.NET CORE MVC 6 on .NET Framework 4.6 (Full .Net framework)**
- **ASP.NET CORE MVC 6 on .NET Core (.NetCoreApp 1.1)**

What is the difference performance between all of these?

I have to rewrite some of my code to go through the net core

Comment: There is no  ASP.NET CORE MVC 6 . Do you mean asp.net mvc 6 on full framework vs asp.net core on .net core ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no ASP.NET CORE MVC 6. Do you mean asp.net mvc 6 on full framework vs asp.NET Core on .NET Core ? From the latest benchmarks for asp.NET Core

[image: ASP.NET Core and asp.net mvc benchmarks]
[image: Request per second]

- [benchmarks](https://github.com/aspnet/benchmarks)
- [ASP.NET Core exceeds 1.15 Million RPS](https://www.ageofascent.com/2016/02/18/asp-net-core-exeeds-1-15-million-requests-12-6-gbps/)

If you would like to check out the general run-time performance for .NET Core vs full .net framework

- [run-time performance](http://codinggorilla.domemtech.com/?p=1499)

If you would like to migrate to ASP.NET Core , You may want to refer not only performance

- [choosing .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)
- [porting to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/index)
- [SO post on difference between frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063837/whats-the-difference-between-net-core-net-framework-and-xamarin)

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite bit old now, and as of today, there is not doubt that asp.net 5 (and 6) is far ahead of older versions.
Also when you want to compare web frameworks, then the best source of truth is here : https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks