# VS 2017 Console Application (C#)

Tags: .net, visual-studio

There are 2 options when creating a project in Visual Studio 2017. The .NET Core one and the other one is .NET Framework .

What are the differences between the two? Which one should I choose and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between .NET Core, .NET Framework, and Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063837/whats-the-difference-between-net-core-net-framework-and-xamarin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developers use the .NET framework to create Windows desktop applications and server based applications. This includes ASP.NET web applications. .NET Core is used to create server applications that run on Windows, Linux and Mac. It does not currently support creating desktop applications with a user interface.

Ref: https://stackify.com/net-core-vs-net-framework/

Windows desktop application has graphical user interface which doesn't run inside the browser such as windows form applications.

Comment: what are desktop applications?