# .NET Core vs.NET Framework as to scalability

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I was reading about how .NET core 2.0 is very much focused on performance and scalability. I was considering migrating an asp.net web api to asp.net core but before investing time on this I was looking for proved evidence that this porting is worth investing time. Someone able to share any evidence on this topic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between .NET Core, .NET Framework, and Xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063837/whats-the-difference-between-net-core-net-framework-and-xamarin)

Comment: .net core is the future of net, 4.8 is the last version of .net framework, and the next release will be net 5, based on net core - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-is-the-future-of-net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

microsoft migrated bing to .net core and has some interesting statistics about it. you can view it here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/bing-com-runs-on-net-core-2-1/

Comment: This is very interesting information @HentaiLord, thank you for sharing

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23306/10-ASP-NET-Performance-and-Scalability-Secrets