# Visual Studio 2022 - Could not load file or assembly 'WASimCommander.WASimClient...'

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a tool to connect my own Hardware, connected through USB, with Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020. I have already quite some experience with SimConnect and WASM (I wrote my own tutorial on the MSFS forum [here](https://forums.flightsimulator.com/t/simconnect-wasm-combined-project-using-vs2019/486871)).

Thanks to some feedback on the MSFS forum, I came across a very powerful WASM implementation called [WASimCommander](https://github.com/mpaperno/WASimCommander/tree/main) written by Max Paperno. This concept is on another level, and I want to try it out myself. After having explored some examples, I want to create my own application using this.

Unfortunately, I have trouble getting started. Let me explain all the steps.

Because this is really a new start, this time I wanted to use the "Windows Forms App" using c#. In the past, I was using the .NET Framework, but I found a topic on this forum that explained that "Windows Forms App" is the future (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304110/difference-between-windows-forms-app-vs-windows-forms-app-net-framework)).

[image]

WASimCommander has a wrapper for C# development. It has the dll's for different NET versions.

[image]

When creating the new "Windows Forms App", I'm asked for the .NET version to use. As Visual Studio itself suggests ".NET 6.0", because of the "Long Term Support", I don't see a reason why not using this.

[image]

Next thing I did was adding the reference to "WASimCommander.WASimClient.dll", which is the C# wrapper. I choose the version that is compatible with "net6" (see folder structure above).

[image]

I also changed the target platform to x64, because that's also required to work with the WASimCommander.
[image]

The only coding I did is adding a button in the form and adding the below in Form1.cs.

```
using WASimCommander.CLI.Enums;
using WASimCommander.CLI.Structs;
using WASimCommander.CLI.Client;

namespace WASimCommander_Test
{
    public partial class WASimCommander_Test_Form : Form
    {
        public WASimCommander_Test_Form()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTest_01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create
            WASimClient client = new WASimClient(1965);  // "CSTESTER"  :)

            // delete the client
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This shouldn't do more than create a WASimCommander client, and then immediately dispose it. This is the simplest thing I can do, and is based on other sample code, so should work.

But when I run the code, and press the button in my form, I'm getting the below:

[image]

It's strange, because I don't see any warnings in my References.

[image]

So no clue what is going on here.

**Edit1**: I created a new app (same way as above), and when I add the reference to the dll, I get the below. I forgot to mention this earlier.

[image]

**Edit2**: I tried with "Windows Froms App (.NET Framework)", using ".NET Framework 4.8", and used the dll from "net46", but still the same issue.

**Edit3**: I now used the dll from "net46" in my original "Windows Form App" (using ".NET 6.0"), and now it seems to work. I am really, really lost now! Good news is that it works, but I still would like to receive some answers on what is going on here. I have the feeling that I'm completely lost in what platform to use, and what dll to use, and only made it work by pure luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `net6` folder, there's a .ini file and ijwhost.dll, manually copy them to your project folder in Explorer, then in VS right click your project, add existing and include those files. Change their `Copy to Output Directory` to either Copy Always or Copy if Newer. What happens is the wrapper requires those two files too but since it can't directly reference them through .NET dependencies, VS doesn't automatically include them when you're adding the assembly dependency.

Comment: That seems to work as a charm! Thanks a million! I'm a hobby programmer, and am now wondering "how should I have known this!". I also checked - it seems that the ini file is not required (if missing, the library uses some default settings as I could figure out in the documentation).

Comment: https://wasimcommander.max.paperno.us/index.html#autotoc_md15 did say that the .ini should be there, but in general if someone release a library in such folder I'd just assume the entire folder is required and copy them all.