# dotnet run reporting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found'

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-2019

Im getting the following error when running 'dotnet run' on my Mac `OS/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.300/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1216,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks [/Users/tommie/projects/zzz/zzz/zzz.csproj]`

My code is from Visual Studio 8.9 and only supports up to 4.8 on the .net frameworks
However when I look at the 'https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks' 4.8 is not available.  Only 5.0 is available.
5.0 is apparently supported in Visual Studio 8.10 but is not a formal release yet.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8 developer pack is [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer). The current release version of Visual Studio 2019 is 16.10. If you are creating a new project, you'd better use .NET 5.0 rather than .NET Framework of any version, because it is officially ended by MS.

Comment: i'm sorry to ask, but aren't you mixing different things? .Net 5 is different than .Net Framework: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063837/whats-the-difference-between-net-core-net-framework-and-xamarin
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/

Plus, you are using .Net Framework on a Mac? The .NET Framework only supports the Windows operating system.

Comment: @C-JARP I probably am mixing different things. On Mac Visual Studio under project->options->general there is a selection for 'Target Framework' and the selection is '.net framework 4.8'

Comment: @Alsein Visual studio 2019 is 16.10 on windows but not mac

Comment: Note that Visual Studio for Mac is NOT Visual Studio, they are completely different things, so never call it 'Visual Studio'. You'd better use vscode instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this exact error on my Jenkins server performing a job using MSBUILD: `error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.8 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application`. There was some back and forth about Visual Studio and about MacOS which muddled things a little, but for me, installing ".NET Framework 4.8 Developer Pack Offline Installer" as suggested by Alsein corrected my problem. Link here https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer

Answer (score 0):

fixed almost exactly same error in a project with around 20 dependent projects (and multiple target frameworks) by retargetting the parent project to target no higher frameworks than were targetted by any of child projects.