# No option to install .NET framework in VS2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, c#-5.0, c#-6.0

I'm learning ASP.NET on YouTube, I use VS2022 and the teacher in the video uses VS2019. The instructor downloaded ASP.NET in VS installer and I did the same. The instructor used ASP.NET web app (.NET framework) for their project and I searched on my computer and there was no version of ASP.NET web app (.NET framework).

I have tried to install some of the latest upgraded versions, 7.0 and 6.0, but it still doesn't work. The advice I received was to use ASP.NET Core.

Comment: .NET Framework is considered to be more or less outdated nowadays and for new projects it makes sense to start with .NET (Core). Several links for deeper dive - [.NET vs. .NET Framework for server apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063837/whats-the-difference-between-net-core-net-framework-and-xamarin. In short - search for ASP.NET Core tutorials (you can start with official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/introduction-to-aspnet-core?view=aspnetcore-7.0))

Comment: Yes, find some tutorials with `Asp.net Core`. Use `.Net 7.0` to develop. That is the newest version. Asp.net based on `.Net Framework` is more than 20 years old and outdated.

Comment: @PoulBak - more than 20 years old is a *little* hyperbolic. Yes, .NET 1.0 came out in 2002 but the ASP.Net of e.g. 2013 was quite a different beast from the one of 2002.

Comment: @PoulBak -thanks .I choose ASP.NET Core for my project

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I primarily meant asp.net webforms, which was 'repaired' many times, but definitely outdated and not for a new developer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you install VS 2022, you have the option to install .NET and ASP.NET. The main difference between ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core is that the latest is a lighter, more portable.

Code wise, the difference is that you have to include a bit more stuff when coding with ASP.NET Core, but that's not really a problem.

In short, if you redo your VS install by ticking the two options stated above, you should be able to see ASP.NET Web Application, but you can totally go with ASP.NET Core and you should not encounter big differences compared to the teacher on Youtube!

Have a good one :)