# Does ASP.NET Core web application targeting full dotnet framework work in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core application developed on top of full framework (4.6.1) to IIS. Right now the code is just the base template code created using the Visual Studio "ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) option. The code compiles fine but when I publish it to Local IIS, it fails to start. I get error like

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.ApplicationEnvironment.GetEntryAssembly()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.ApplicationEnvironment..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.BuildHostingServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
```

My project.json looks like this

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net461": { }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

The same application if targeted towards dotnetcore instead of dotnet461 works fine. All MS documentation seems to say that this scenario is possible and is supported. Has something changed in RTM?

Comment: Yes, it should and it does (I checked). The first things I always do in such cases are:

1. check if it runs from commandline in source directory, with `dotnet run`
2. check if i runs from commandline in the published IIS website root (there should be an executable, like `myaspapp.exe`
3. remove everything from `%userprofile%/.nuget`, run `dotnet restore` again, remove everything from IIS website root, then run `dotnet publish` again.

Comment: @qbik A combination of your step 3 and pawel's issue below seem to have fixed my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you published the same application targeting `netcoreapp1.0` first and then you the `net4x` version then I think it is a bug in Web Deploy. I hit a similar problem when publishing to Azure - https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/801#issuecomment-227920473. I fixed it by first manually deleting all the contents in the target folder and then publishing the application targeting `net4x` again (https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/801#issuecomment-228123238). I think Web Deploy leaves some dlls behind or does not update if the names are the same and they are then picked up but fail because they are not matching the target framework and their dependencies are missing. I also found that checking the checkbox in Web Deploy to delete files at the destination did not fix the problem and opened an issue on that.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. My problems started with azure publish and then continued with local IIS. I had initially targeted the app on netcoreapp1.0. Created a brand new app and published it locally and on azure and now everything seems to be working.

Comment: Same solution worked for me. If someone (like me) doesn't know where to delete the files, there is a management app here https://<yourwebsitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole where you can remove or add files.