# Using ASP.NET Core features in full .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, aspnetboilerplate, .net-4.6.1

Referring to [Why use the full .NET Framework with ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865054/why-use-the-full-net-framework-with-asp-net-core), it appears .NET 4.7.2 is the way to go forward?

Our existing application targets .NET 4.6.1 using ASP.NET Boilerplate.

Is it mandatory to migrate to .NET 4.7.* in order to leverage ASP.NET Core 2.1 features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to migrate to .NET 4.7.* in order to leverage ASP.NET Core 2.1 features.

> ASP.NET Core 2.x is made up of .NET Standard libraries. Apps written with .NET Standard 2.0 run anywhere that .NET Standard 2.0 is supported.
>
> ASP.NET Core 2.x is supported on .NET Framework versions compatible with .NET Standard 2.0:
>
> - .NET Framework 4.7.1 and later is strongly recommended.
> - .NET Framework 4.6.1 and later.

You only need to migrate to .NET 4.7.2 if you need features in [Announcing .NET Framework 4.7.2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/30/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-2/):

> - ASP.NET – Dependency Injection in WebForms
> - ASP.NET – SameSite Cookie
> - ClickOnce – Per-monitor support for WPF and HDPI-aware ClickOnce deployed apps
> - ClickOnce – Enable SHA256 timestamping of Deployment Manifests
> - SQL – Azure AD Universal and Multi-factor Authentication Support
> - BCL – Cryptographic Improvements
> - BCL – ZLib decompression support to DeflateStream
> - BCL – Additional Collection APIs
> - WorkflowDesigner High Contrast Improvements
> - WPF – Finding ResourceDictionaries by Source
> - WPF – Finding ResourceDictionary owners
> - WPF – Finding StaticResource references

References:

- [ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#aspnet-core-targeting-net-framework)
- [.NET Standard implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)

Answer (score 5):

To use .NET Core 2.1 features, you need to target .NET Core 2.1

There is .NET *Standard*, which is an intersection of features that are available in a range of implementations, including .NET Core and .NET Framework. If you target .NET *Standard* (some specific version), then you can use the features available in that version of .NET Standard, and it should *run* on either .NET Framework 4.7.2 or .NET Core 2.1.

As a general guide: libraries (such as Aspnet Boilerplate) should now - where possible - target .NET Standard, but will often have a multi-target build to allow them to internally *exploit* target-specific features of specific frameworks (perhaps using the enhanced "span" or SIMD capabilities in .NET Core).

Application code should (and *must*, if it is an executable) target a specific framework such as .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Answer (score 2):

For real, if you're building an application using .NET Core/Standard, but in your application, you may have some reference that using .NET Framework, it **must** be a big problem.

---

A story: I'm building a web application using ASP.NET Core, in this application, I want to have an extension that converting HTML to pdf.

I've tried to searched on Google and found a plugin that is called: `itextsharp`. And the problem comes from here.

`itextsharp` is using .NET Framework while my main project is using .NET Core. Since I want to create a class library to build this extension, I have 3 options:

1. Using .NET Core class library.
2. Using .NET Standard class library.
3. Using .NET Framwork class library.

All of them can be refered to the main project. **BUT**:

I **cannot** use `itextsharp` references (`itextsharp.dll`, `itextsharp.xtra.dll`, `itextsharp.pdfa.dll`, `itextsharp.xmlworker.dll`...) in .NET Core/Standard class libray. All of them can run only on target .NET Framework.

*(I haven't mentioned about how to convert the code to target .NET Standard or Core because of license yet)*

And my solution is: Build a .NET Framework app and publish it to `exe` file before appending to the main project as a reference.

*P/S: For now, `itextsharp` has a Core version but I think it's not good enough (problems about: displaying images, fonts with unicode text, style tag...).*

---

Totally, if you want to build some app that is using target .NET X, you must make sure all of the references can use target .NET X, too.

---

Another example: if you want to build a class library that using `Razor class library`. You **must** make sure that all of the references are using target .NET Core/Standard. Because `Razor class library` **cannot** refer to .NET Framework class library.